# Possible orders of the elements of the alternating group $A_n$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

What are the possible orders of the elements of the alternating group $A_n$, that $n\in \{P,P+1,P+2,2P,2P+1\}$, where $P$ is the set of primes numbers?

Comment: Think about cycles, remember the order of a permutation is equal to the least common multiple of the cycle lengths (in the canonical decompositon). A permutation is in $A_n$ if and only if it has an even number of cycles of even length.

Comment: Does the problem ask specifically for $A_n$ or for some particular value of $n$? I don't think we are going to be able to give a "closed", "concise" answer. Since the final answer is going to depend heavily on the distribution of the primes.

Comment: There is no simple closed formula for the largest order of an element of $S_n$. This function is known as *Landau's function*: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function